# Is it possible to an app that listens to the Windows audio input to let the system save power?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, power-saving

From the moment we call Win API's `WaveInOpen` method the system won't sleep nor hibernate until this stream is closed.
Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess: try calling SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS) on the same thread that called WaveInOpen.

Comment: This method returns that the thread execution state is already equal to ES_CONTINUOUS before and after the WaveInOpen call

Comment: Well, worth a try.  You are looking at driver hacking next, no idea how to tackle that.